# Adjective to describe object that has connections between its elements

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Example: a social network is  [...] as users are connected by their friendships.

I could think of a social network is connected but it sounds like the social networks connect to each other.

Comment: interconnected:
having all constituent parts linked or connected

Comment: *a social network's users are connected by their friendships*. Not sure I see the need for any other word at all?

Comment: The most common word is probably "networked", which is a bit redundant in your example. Perhaps the expression "internally connected". You could try "intralinked"; if it wasn't a word it is now.

Comment: Surely a network 'has connections between its elements' by definition - why do you need an adjective to say so?

Comment: A social network is a metaphor. What terms you use to describe it define the metaphor you're using, which you don't specify. _Network_ and _connection_ are very vague terms and can mean practically anything, whether you're describing imaginary theoretical material or physical phenomena.  Perhaps a look at graph theory might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

How about *contextualized*?

Definition＊ of contexture:

> 1: the act, process, or manner of weaving parts into a whole
> also : a structure so formed
>
> *// a contexture of lies*
>
> 2: CONTEXT

Definition†  of context:

> 1: the parts of a discourse that surround a word or passage and can throw light on its meaning
>
> 2: the interrelated conditions in which something exists or occurs : ENVIRONMENT, SETTING
>
> *// the historical context of the war*

＊ https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contexture
† https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/context

which brings to mind one of my favorite of all quotes, by anyone, this one happening to be from Marcus Aurelius' *Meditations*:

> Constantly regard the universe as one living being, having one substance and one soul; and observe how all things have reference to one perception, the perception of this one living being; and how all things act with one movement; and how all things are the cooperating causes of all things which exist; observe too the continuous spinning of the thread and the **contexture** of the *web*.
>
> *(emphasis added by me)*
>
> Marcus Aurelius
> IV, 40 - Meditations (c. 161–180 CE) - Book IV

Uncanny almost - the implied prophesy of the Internet, some 1800 years ahead of his time....

And as for my own example of use of the word as it relates to the *context* of your question, how about:

*A social network is a **contextualized**, 21st century modern digital labyrinth of often implausibly numerous connections of its users "friendships" - each one individual's having further degrees of interconnectedness, *ad infinitum*. Thus, it is as though it exists as a single contexture — *"The Social Network"* — one could surely say; deserving of its definite article more so in infamy than by any remaining universal awe and acceptance, in recent times.*

Comment: It's a good quote, but the Internet was dubbed the web for a reason.  Do you need to imply prophecy?  It's not  motorways like 1-95/Nationale 7/Bundesautobahn foretold the coming of the Information Superhighway :)

Comment: Oh I know! Lol! It's sheer eerie coincidence! But then again, I would argue and do believe it was predictable. But yes the words specifically are surely largely etymological coincidence. And yes I'm aware of how important those spin-threading ancient three sister gods were in ancient times, and I'm no expert on ancient literature but I'm pretty positive that really is what Marcus is referring to. The Fates? Were they?